# Integrate $ \ \int_C (1+y)dx-e^{\sin y}\, dy \ $

Tags: calculus, integration

Integrate $ \ \int_C (1+y)dx-e^{\sin y}\, dy \ $  , where $ \ C \ $ is the parabola $ y=x^2 \ $ from $ \ (-1,1) \ \ to \ \ (1,1) \ $

**Answer:**

The parametric equation of $ \ y=x^2 \ $ from $ \ (-1,1) \ \ to \ \ (1,1) \ $ is given by

$ x=t, \ y=t^2 , \ \ -1 \leq t \leq 1 \ $

Thus,

$ \int_C (1+y)dx-e^{\sin y}\, dy \\ = \int_{-1}^{1} [(1+t^2)\,dt-e^{\sin (t^2)} 2t\, dt] \\ = \int_{-1}^{1} [(1+t^2)-2t e^{\sin (t^2)}]\, dt \\ = \,? $

**Am I right so far ?**

**Further how to calculate the last part?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have: $$y = x^2 \implies dy = 2x\, dx$$ giving us: $$I = \int_{C} e^{\sin y}\, dy = \int_{-1}^{1} e^{\sin x^2} 2x\, dx $$ Now, note that this is an odd function, so $$I =0$$